# Getting internet for Galaxy Tab 2 from Galaxy S3

Tags: tethering, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

Is there a way to use the Galaxy Tab 2 with my Galaxy S3 (SPRINT) to get an internet connection?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, very easily actually.

**To Make your S3 emit a WiFi network**

1. Enable 'WiFi Tethering' in `System Settings->More->Tethering and Portable Hotspot->Portable WiFi Hotspot`.
2. Configure the hotspot (name, password etc), in the `Setup WiFi Hotspot` menu.

**To Connect your Tablet to the WiFi network**

1. Enter the tablets WiFi settings, and turn WiFi on.
2. Select the WiFi network you configured on your S3).
3. Select connect. If you setup a password, you need to enter it.

**Other Info**

If you do not see the WiFi Hotspot option, then your network has disabled it. If you're rooted you could use an app such as [WiFi Tethering](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=og.android.tether) - just be aware that this will produce an Ad-Hoc hotspot, and Stock Android cannot connect to these types of hostspots.

There is currently no way, AFAIK, to create a standard WiFi hotspot without using the stock android tethering system.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you have `3G/LTE` connection on your `Galaxy S3` and want to use that connection on your `Galaxy tab2`, so you would have internet on it. OK! here is the solution:

**On Galaxy S3:**

- Enable Internet (3G/LTE mobile data)
- Go to Settings -> Wireless & Networks -> Tethering & portable hotspot (the path and names may be different on your phone)
- Enable **Portable Wifi hotspot**
- Click on "`Configure Wifi hotspot`" and define a desired SSID and password for your network.

**Now, on your Galaxy Tab 2:**

- Go to settings and enable Wi-fi
- In the list of available wireless networks, find your wireless network created on Galaxy S3, and tap on it to connect
- Enter password of the network you created on S3 and then it should connect to your Galaxy S3 and use its internet connection.

more info: http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168932

- If your network (Sprint) has disabled Tethering on the phone, you may want to use 3rd party apps to enable tethering (Liam has pointed to one of them in his answer)

Comment: This is exactly what I said, just in another wording.

Comment: @LiamW Sorry, when I started typing my answer, there wasn't any answer on this question, and just after I clicked "Post", I found that you have been quicker than me :) (however your answer wasn't structured and step-by-step at first, before you edited it). BTW, if you think my answer is a copy of yours, I would delete it.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to root my Samsung S3 and install a WiFi Tether apk file so I can get free internet on my Samsung Tab 2.

Comment: Not exactly an answer - for starters, what wifi tether app are you referring to when in fact there's an inbuilt Wifi Tethering into the ROM....?

Answer (score 0):

Samsung galaxy tab 2 and Motorola photon you can get internet thru Bluetooth

Comment: Uhhh... care to elaborate more instead of posting one line answers?

Comment: What do you need Motorola photon for?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to enable WiFi Tethering. 
Bluetooth also works.

Comment: Perhaps you should expand your answer. It doesn't currently add anything, as the other answers have explained this (and in more detail).